# Stop Timer on return to previous Activity

Tags: android, android-timer

I have created a `timer` that starts timing on a `handleClick()` and continues timing throughout the `app`. When I return to the `firstActivity` I would like the `timer` to `stop` in the `onResume()`. however whenever I return to the `firstActivity` I get the following error below. How do I solve this?

#### Error

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.example.warrenedy.julyfinal.TimeTracker2.isTracking()' on a null object reference`

#### Code Below

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    prepareActivityTextsAndButtons();
    prepareTimingButtons();
    mTimeTracker2.stopTracker();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Onresume call", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


public void handleClick(View v) {

    if (DBG) Log.d(LOG_TAG, "handleClick()..");
    if (!mServiceBound) return;
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.button_activity_start_stop:

            onActivityButtonClick(v);
            break;
 }
}

 private void onActivityButtonClick(View v) {

    if (DBG)
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onMeditateButtonClick().. tracking " + mTimeTracker2.isTracking());
    ToggleButton button = (ToggleButton) v;

    if (mTimeTracker2.isTracking()) {
        if (mCurrentTrackingActivity == null) return;
        if (button == mButtonActivityTimers[mCurrentTrackingActivity.ordinal()]) {
            mTimeTracker2.stopTracker();

            Utils2.playStopAudio(getApplicationContext());
            //  button.setText(R.string.str_start);


            mCurrentTime.setText(Utils2.secToString(0));
            button.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Code Continued

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (DBG) Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate()..");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_meditation_tracker);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    mContext = getApplicationContext();
    
    mSharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(Utils.MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    exercise_star = sharedpreferences.getInt("exercise_star", 0);
    meditation_star = sharedpreferences.getInt("meditation_star", 0);
    study_star = sharedpreferences.getInt("study_star", 0);

    isAlarmSet = sharedpreferences.getBoolean("isAlarmSet", false);


    /* Retrieve a PendingIntent that will perform a broadcast */

    mActivity = MeditationTrackerActivity.this;
    mButtonSavePoints = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save_points);
    mButtonRestorePoints = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_restore_points);
    btnHelpBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHelp);
    ACTIVITY_NAMES = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.activity_names);

    mCurrentTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_current_time);
    mCurrentTime.setText(Utils2.secToString(0));


    if (!isAlarmSet) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sharedpreferences.edit();
        ed.putBoolean("isAlarmSet", true);
        ed.commit();
        startAlarmService();
    }
    isAuthenticated = sharedpreferences.getBoolean("isAuth", true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {

        if (!isAuthenticated) {
            clientAuthenticationFromServer();
        } else {
            startService();

        }

    } else {
        insertPermissionWrapper();
    }
 }

### StartAlarmService

    public void startAlarmService() {
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(MeditationTrackerActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MeditationTrackerActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
        mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Calendar firingCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar currentCal = Calendar.getInstance();

        firingCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23); // At the hour you wanna fire
        firingCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45); // Particular minute
        firingCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); // particular second

        long intendedTime = firingCal.getTimeInMillis();
        long currentTime = currentCal.getTimeInMillis();


        if (intendedTime >= currentTime) {
            
            mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, intendedTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        } else {
            
            firingCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            intendedTime = firingCal.getTimeInMillis();

            mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, intendedTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

        }
       
        Toast.makeText(this, "Main Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

### CancelAlarm

    public void cancelAlarmService() {
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


### StartService

    private void startService() {

        Intent serIntent = new Intent(this, TimeTrackingService2.class);
        startService(serIntent);
        bindService(serIntent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

### UpdateCurrentTime 

    private void updateCurrentTime() {
        Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        mCurrentTime.setText(sdf.format(date));
    }

### ClientAuthenticationFromServer
    
    private void clientAuthenticationFromServer() {
        if (Utils2.getConnectivityStatus(mContext)) {
            new Auth(mContext, mActivity).execute(Utils2.URL_VALIDATE_CLIENT);
        } else {
            Utils2.alertPopup(mContext, "You are not connected to internet.kindly connect with internet and try again.The internet is needed only first time for the authentication of client.After authentication no need of internet.", mActivity);


        }
    }

###Task Complete

     @Override
     public void onTaskComplete(boolean result) {
        if (!result) {
            Utils2.alertPopup(mContext, "You are not a valid client.Contact with the owner of the App.", mActivity);
            return;
        } else {

            SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sharedpreferences.edit();
            ed.putBoolean("isAuth", true);
            ed.commit();
            startService();
        }
    }

### OnStart

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();


//        updateCurrentTime();
//        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
//        registerReceiver(mTimeTickReceiver, filter);

      }

###OnStop

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        //   unregisterReceiver(mTimeTickReceiver);

    }

### onDestroy

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mServiceBound) {
            unbindService(mServiceConnection);
        }
    }

### onTimeButtonClick

      private void onTimeButtonClick(View v) {
        if (DBG) Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onClick() timebutton.. tracking" + mTimeTracker2.isTracking());
        ToggleButton button = (ToggleButton) v;
        if (DBG) Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onClick() timebutton.. checked ? " + button.isChecked());
        if (mTimeTracker2.isTracking()) {
            showStopToast();
            Utils2.playStopAudio(getApplicationContext());
            button.setChecked(false);
            return;
        } else {
            Utils2.playStartAudio(getApplicationContext());
            if (button.isChecked()) {
                if (mCurrentCheckedButton != null) mCurrentCheckedButton.setChecked(false);
                int time = (Integer) v.getTag();
                mCountDownSecs = time;
                mCurrentCheckedButton = button;
            } else {
                mCountDownSecs = 0;
                mCurrentCheckedButton = null;
            }
        }
      }

###ShowStopToast 

      private void showStopToast() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please stop running activity..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }


### onTimerProgress

      @Override
      public void onTimerProgress(int sec, ACTIVITIES activity) {
        if (mCurrentTrackingActivity == null) {
            mCurrentTrackingActivity = activity;
        }
        
        mCurrentTime.setText(Utils2.secToString(sec));
        if (activity == ACTIVITIES.STUDY) {
            if (sec == 3600) {
                mTimeTracker2.stopTracker();
            }
        }
      }

### onTimerFinish

      @Override
      public void onTimerFinish(int end, ACTIVITIES activity) {
      
        mCurrentTime.setText(Utils2.secToString(end));
        mButtonActivityTimers[activity.ordinal()].setChecked(false);
        mCurrentTrackingActivity = null;

        Utils2.playStopAudio(getApplicationContext());
       
     }

    private void prepareActivityTextsAndButtons() {

        for (int i = 0; i < ACTIVITY_COUNT; i++) {
            View parent = findViewById(ACTIVITY_LAYOUT_IDS[i]);
            mTextActivityNames[i] = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.tv_activity_name);
            mTextActivityNames[i].setText(ACTIVITY_NAMES[i]);

            //mTextActivityTimers[i] = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.tv_timer_progress);
            mRatingBars[i] = (RatingBar) parent.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);

            mButtonActivityTimers[i] = (ToggleButton) parent.findViewById(R.id.button_activity_start_stop);
            mButtonActivityTimers[i].setText(null);
            mButtonActivityTimers[i].setTextOn(null);
            mButtonActivityTimers[i].setTextOff(null);
            mButtonActivityTimers[i].setTag(ACTIVITIES.values()[i]);
        }

    }

    private void prepareTimingButtons() {
        mTimingButtons = new ToggleButton[7];
        mTimingButtons[0] = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.button_timer_0);
        addTextToTimingButtons(5, mTimingButtons[0]);
    }

    private void addTextToTimingButtons(int min, Button button) {
        // button.setText(min + " " + getString(R.string.str_min));
        button.setTag(min * 60);
    }

    public void onCustomTimeStarted(int secs) {
        if (DBG) Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCustomTimeStarted : secs " + secs);
        if (mTimeTracker2.isTracking()) {
            showStopToast();
        } else {
            int oneday = 24 * 3600;
            if (secs > oneday) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Adjusted to 24 hrs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                secs = oneday;
            } else if (secs < 60) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Should be at least a minute.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            mTimingButtons[6].setChecked(true);
            mTimingButtons[6].setTag(secs);
            onTimeButtonClick(mTimingButtons[6]);
            //mTimeTracker2.startTracker(secs, this);
            //mButtonMeditate.setText(R.string.meditate_stop);
        }
    }

    private boolean addPermission(List<String> permissionsList, String permission) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                permissionsList.add(permission);
                // Check for Rationale Option
                if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission))
                    return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void insertPermissionWrapper() {
        List<String> permissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<String>();

        final List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE))
            permissionsNeeded.add("READ_PHONE_STATE");

        if (permissionsList.size() > 0) {
            if (permissionsNeeded.size() > 0) {
                // Need Rationale
                String message = "You need to grant access to " + permissionsNeeded.get(0);
                for (int i = 1; i < permissionsNeeded.size(); i++)
                    message = message + ", " + permissionsNeeded.get(i);
                showMessageOKCancel(message,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                                    requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                                            REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                return;
            }
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                        REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            }
            return;
        } else {

            if (!isAuthenticated) {
                clientAuthenticationFromServer();
            } else {

                startService();
            }
        }

        // insertDummyContact();
    }

    private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(MeditationTrackerActivity.this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .create()
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {
                Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                // Initial
                perms.put(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

                // Fill with results
                for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                    perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
                // Check for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        ) {
                    // All Permissions Granted
                    if (!isAuthenticated) {
                        clientAuthenticationFromServer();
                    } else {

                        startService();
                    }
                } else {
                    // Permission Denied
                    Toast.makeText(MeditationTrackerActivity.this, "Some Permission is Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    finish();
                }
            }
            break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }

    private void setBootReceiverEnabled(int componentEnabledState) {
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, DeviceBootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,
                componentEnabledState,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    };
```

#### TimeTracker2.class

```
public class TimeTracker2 {

private static final int MSG_TRACKER_STOPPED = 1;
private static final int MSG_TRACKER_PROGRESS_UPDATE = 2;

private Context mContext;
private boolean mIsTrackingInProgress;

private TrackerServiceCallback mServiceCallback;
private TimerProgressCallback2 mProgressCallback;

private Timer mTimer = new Timer();
private TimerHandler mTimerHandler = new TimerHandler();
private TimerTask mIncrementTask, mDecrementTask;
private int mCounter;
private int mMaxCounter;
private MeditationTrackerActivity.ACTIVITIES mCurrentTrackingActivity;


private class IncrementTask extends TimerTask {

    IncrementTask() {
        mCounter = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mCounter++;
        mTimerHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_TRACKER_PROGRESS_UPDATE);
    }
}

private class DecrementTask extends TimerTask {


    DecrementTask(int sec) {
        mCounter = sec;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (mCounter == 0) {
            ToneGenerator toneGenerator = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
            toneGenerator.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_PIP, 500);
            cancel();
            mTimerHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_TRACKER_STOPPED);
            return;
        }
        mCounter --;
        mTimerHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_TRACKER_PROGRESS_UPDATE);
    }
}

public interface TimerProgressCallback2 {
    void onTimerProgress(int sec, MeditationTrackerActivity.ACTIVITIES activity);
    void onTimerFinish(int end, MeditationTrackerActivity.ACTIVITIES activity);
}


public TimeTracker2(Context context, TrackerServiceCallback serviceCallback) {
    mContext = context;
    mServiceCallback = serviceCallback;
}


public void startTracker(int time_secs, TimerProgressCallback2 callback, MeditationTrackerActivity.ACTIVITIES activity) {
    if (mIsTrackingInProgress) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "startTracker().. inProgress!!");
        return;
    }
    mMaxCounter = time_secs;
    mProgressCallback = callback;
    mIsTrackingInProgress = true;
    mServiceCallback.onTrackerStarted(true);
    mDecrementTask = new DecrementTask(time_secs);
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(mDecrementTask, 0, 1000);
    mCurrentTrackingActivity = activity;
}

public void startTracker(TimerProgressCallback2 callback, MeditationTrackerActivity.ACTIVITIES activity) {
    if (mIsTrackingInProgress) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "startTracker().. inProgress!!");
        return;
    }
    mMaxCounter = 0;
    mProgressCallback = callback;
    mIsTrackingInProgress = true;
    mServiceCallback.onTrackerStarted(true);
    mIncrementTask = new IncrementTask();
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(mIncrementTask, 0, 1000);
    mCurrentTrackingActivity = activity;
}

public void setTimerProgressCallback(TimerProgressCallback2 callback) {
    if (!mIsTrackingInProgress) return;
    mProgressCallback = callback;
}

public void removeTimerProgressCallback() {
    mProgressCallback = null;
}


public void stopTracker() {
    if (!mIsTrackingInProgress) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "stopTracker().. Tracker NOT started!!");
        return;
    }
    mIsTrackingInProgress = false;
    mServiceCallback.onTrackerStarted(false);
    if (mProgressCallback != null) mProgressCallback.onTimerFinish(mCounter, mCurrentTrackingActivity);
    mProgressCallback = null;
    if (mIncrementTask != null) mIncrementTask.cancel();
    if (mDecrementTask != null) mDecrementTask.cancel();

    updateDb();
    mCurrentTrackingActivity = null;
}

public boolean isTracking() {
    return mIsTrackingInProgress;
}

public MeditationTrackerActivity.ACTIVITIES getCurrentTrackingActivity() {
    return mCurrentTrackingActivity;
}

private class TimerHandler extends Handler {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (DBG) Log.d(LOG_TAG, "handleMessage()..");
        switch (msg.what) {
            case MSG_TRACKER_PROGRESS_UPDATE:
                if (mProgressCallback != null) mProgressCallback.onTimerProgress(mCounter, mCurrentTrackingActivity);
                break;

            case MSG_TRACKER_STOPPED:
            default:
                stopTracker();
                break;
        }
    }
}

private void updateDb() {
    final int secs = mMaxCounter > 0 ? mMaxCounter - mCounter : mCounter;
    final MeditationTrackerActivity.ACTIVITIES activity = mCurrentTrackingActivity;
    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TrackerDb3.insertOrUpdateMeditation(mContext, secs, activity);
        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: The error shows that the instance `mTimeTracker2` is null at that moment. How are you creating and handling the timer?

Comment: can you mention on create method code

Comment: I have added all the code for this `activity` that starts the `timer`